# What does "bring to front and bring to back" on panels c# form mean

Tags: c#, forms

I am using c# drag and drop panels .the panels keep appearing and disappearing.Also i need help with panel box functionality words like "bring to front and bring to back" i think this is what is messing my panels up.What do they mean?

Comment: Bring to front and back changes the z-order. Can you be a bit more specific with what your problem/question is?

Answer (score 11):

The Windows Forms Designer has a concept called `Z-order`. When two controls overlap, the Z-order determines which control will show up on top.

For example, suppose you have two controls called `textBox1` and `pictureBox1` on a Windows Form. Programatically, `this` refers to the Windows Form itself, `Controls` is the default list of controls in that Form, and `textBox1` and is the actual control we are changing.

Selecting the menu option `Bring to Front` is equivalent to calling the control's `BringToFront()` method. This moves the control to the beginning of the default Controls collection of the Windows Form. So if you call `Bring To Front` on `textBox1`, it will show up above all other controls on your Form. Programatically,

```
// Bring the control in front of all other controls
this.textBox1.BringToFront();
```

Selecting the menu option `Send to Back` is equivalent to calling the control's `SendToBack()` method. This moves the control to the end of the default Controls collection of the Windows Form. So if you call `Send To Back` on `textBox1`, it will show up behind all other controls on your Form. Programatically,

```
// Send the control behind all other controls
this.textBox1.SendToBack();
```

You can also have finer control over the ordering programmatically. There is no way to do this in the UI. So:

```
// Put the control at the 2nd index in the Controls collection of this Form
this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.textBox1, 2);
```

This page [Layering Objects on Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164035.aspx) gives some more details.

The page [Windows Forms Controls: Z-order and Copying Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164035.aspx) has examples on how to control Z-order programmatically.

Comment: what is "Me"? i do not understand this

Comment: @user2315477 ah that's VB, equivalent to "this" in C#. Let me modify the answer a bit :)